# Otimização de condição

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

É possível fazer uma comparação (se igual a 1 ou igual a `null`) mais simples do que a feita em meu código?

```
@((Model.Visibilidade == 1 || Model.Visibilidade == null) ? "checked" : "")
```

Comment: o `Visibilidade` é um `int?` assim?

Comment: Isso mesmo, é um `int?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não dá.

Eu faria assim:

```
@((Model.Visibilidade == null || Model.Visibilidade == 1) ? "checked" : "")
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/ConditionInView.cs).

Neste caso não dá problema porque é um `int?`, mas em casos de tipos por referência daria erro. Se for nulo e tentar fazer a comparação com um valor vai dar erro, então é o correto é comprar o nulo primeiro. Pra manter a consistência eu sempre faria nesta ordem, mesmo que neste caso possa comparar o valor primeiro.

Comment: Realmente a ordem está invertida, deveria dar erro, mas não deu. Sim é um `int?`

Comment: Não deu porque o valoe é 1, se fosse `null` daria erro.

Comment: Não, o valor realmente é null, o código está em um fomulário de inclusão/alteração, onde não exite valor default para o registro `Model.Visibilidade `

Comment: Isso aqui dá erro `Model.Visibilidade === 1`

Comment: C# não tem `===`. De fato não dá erro, não me lembrava desse comportamento do `int?`, e até faz sentido. Atualizei a resposta.